# cannot return a table grouped by variables in MS SQL server Management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I created the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION categorize (
     @id VARCHAR(5),
     @var1_low INT,
     @var1_high INT,
     @var2_low DECIMAL(18,6),
     @var2_high DECIMAL(18,6)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    (SELECT
        year,
        id,
        COUNT(id) AS totalnum,
        SUM(score) AS var1_sum
     FROM
        database1
     WHERE
        studentid = @id
        AND Score >= @var1_low
        AND Score <= @var1_high
        AND time >= @var2_low
        AND time <= @var2_high
     GROUP BY
        year
     ORDER BY
        year
    )
```

Then it says

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you read the error message, you will see that your options are to specify `TOP` or `FOR XML`, or eliminate the `ORDER BY` clause.   SQL Server is notorious for giving unhelpful error messages, but this isn't one of them.   BTW, you're also going to need to add `id` to your `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ORDER BY clause in your function and write it in your SELECT clause like this

```
SELECT * FROM yourFunction(params) ORDER BY yourColumn
```